# Memory error when loading a very large json file from URL

Tags: python, json

I saw on other similar questions that they use libraries like ijson. But I cannot seem to figure how to use it to fix the problem.

This is the code I have so far:

```
f = urllib.request.urlopen("https://data.medicaid.gov/resource/4qik-skk9.json?$limit=646259")
stuff = ijson.items(f,"")
for items in stuff:
print(items)
```

This is what the json structure looks like:

```
[
    {
        "package_size_code": "60",
        "fda_ther_equiv_code": "NR",
        "fda_application_number": "204153",
        "clotting_factor_indicator": "N",
        "year": "2018",
        "fda_product_name": "LUZU Cream 1% 60gm",
        "labeler_name": "MEDICIS DERMATOLOGICS, INC.",
        "ndc": "99207085060",
        "product_code": "0850",
        "unit_type": "GM",
        "fda_approval_date": "2013-11-14T00:00:00",
        "market_date": "2014-03-14T00:00:00",
        "pediatric_indicator": "N",
        "package_size_intro_date": "2014-03-14T00:00:00",
        "units_per_pkg_size": "60000",
        "labeler_code": "99207",
        "desi_indicator": "1",
        "drug_category": "S",
        "quarter": "3",
        "cod_status": "3"
    },
    {
        "package_size_code": "60",
        "fda_ther_equiv_code": "AB",
        "fda_application_number": "21758",
        "clotting_factor_indicator": "N",
        "year": "2018",
        "fda_product_name": "VANOS CREAM .1%",
        "labeler_name": "MEDICIS DERMATOLOGICS, INC.",
        "ndc": "99207052560",
        "product_code": "0525",
        "unit_type": "GM",
        "fda_approval_date": "2005-02-11T00:00:00",
        "market_date": "2005-02-21T00:00:00",
        "pediatric_indicator": "N",
        "package_size_intro_date": "2005-02-21T00:00:00",
        "units_per_pkg_size": "60000",
        "labeler_code": "99207",
        "desi_indicator": "1",
        "drug_category": "I",
        "quarter": "3",
        "cod_status": "3"
    },
.
.
.
.
]
```

What I'm trying to do is to get all the results and apply some filters to them to get a value. For example, I am trying to get the maximum value for year from all the entries. For that to happen, I think I need to read all the data.

This seems to solve the memory problem:

```
parser = ijson.parse(urllib.request.urlopen('https://data.medicaid.gov/resource/4qik-skk9.json?$limit=646259'))
        for prefix, event, value  in parser:
            #print(prefix)
            print(event)
            #print(value)
```

The data does not come out very neatly but it is progress.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ijson and their documentation isn't extensive, but looking at their [example usage](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/) it appears that in your case you're asking for the entire file at once, which is exactly what you're saying you don't want. Maybe try `ijson.items(f, "item")`?

Comment: Hmmmm let me edit the question. Thanks for bringing that up

Comment: Well, that doesn't really change the problem. You're trying to read the entire JSON file into memory, and your system can't do that. You need to find a way to deal with the items one at a time, which can mean simply saving the entry with the maximum value for year, and checking each subsequent item against it. Better yet, load it all into a database where you can work with it more efficiently.

Comment: I think the approach of loading them into a database makes sense. So you mean I put the values one at a time into like a sqlite database and then do the filtering?

Comment: please check these site:
https://www.ngdata.com/parsing-a-large-json-file-efficiently-and-easily/

Comment: @AvinashPrabhakar Yes. Once you figure out how to process the JSON items one at a time with ijson (or something else), insert them into a database and then use SQL queries to get what you need.

Comment: @glibdud Thanks! It seems to be working when I try the following code: see in updated question